# Laravel 4 logic?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I recently downloaded a version of Laravel 4 and it was only 40kb. Laravel 3.2 was about 3.5mb, my questions are:

- How can I use Laravel 4 completely offline?
- I found out, Laravel 4 core codes was missing, Does it work cloud base or something like it!?
- Which version do you recommend to use? Laravel 3.2 or Laravel 4? ( mostly for local developing )

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you installed Laravel? Using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is as simple as:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

I use Laravel 4 for local development, and it works like a charm!

Comment: In the command line, using Terminal on Mac. You would actually need to install Composer first, so read the docs there. A lot of Laravel is controlled by the command line so it is best to read up on it. If you're an absolute beginner it might be worth reading [this Laravel book](https://leanpub.com/codebright). And yes, use Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

That's mainly because Laravel 4 uses [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to handle dependencies. What you downloaded wasn't exactly Laravel, but rather the structure for it. It's a preset project, with all default Laravel dependencies, so that all you have to do is run a command and download it all.

To use Laravel 4, you'll need to **[install composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/).** After you're done, open your command line, go to the folder where you saved the Laravel files you downloaded and, inside it, type: `php composer install`. This will download all the dependencies needed for the project; that means Laravel files and all of its own dependencies. It may take a while to install, and may seem to be stuck at `Installing dependencies (including require-dev)` for quite a long time, since there are lots of dependencies to be fetched, but that's normal. After it's done, you should see something like this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0)
    Downloading: 100%

    ...

  - Installing laravel/framework (4.0.x-dev 733492c)
    Downloading: 100%

...
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

Now all you have to do is point the root of your webserver to the `/public` folder and start programming. If you ever feel you want to update your dependencies, simply run `composer update`.

**Note:** Remember to enable PHP's `openssl` extension, so composer can download the projects from github, and Apache's `mod_rewrite`, so Laravel pretty URLs work. If you're using Apache, that is.
**Note²:** Whenever you create a new `command`, `controller`, `model`, `migration` or `seed`, you'll have to type `composer dump-autoload` on your console, so composer knows how to autoload it.